# Stack-Overflow exception when adding instance class inside static class from default constructor

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow, default-constructor

```
public class Form
{
    internal static Dictionary<string, Form> Cache = new 
     Dictionary<string, Form>();
    public string FormID{get;set;} = string.Empty;

    public Form()
    {
        if (!Cache.ContainsKey(FormID))
            Cache.Add(FormID, new Form());

       // exception here because new Form() is always called again
    }
}
```

I want to create instance of object of class Form inside Cache. if Cache contains the FormID property then nothing will happened to static dictionary Cache.

**Cache** must hold single instance for each instance from Form that have unique FormID.  this mean each Form instance has instance inside a Cache with same FormID. so creating new instances from cloning the cache will be fast. thats what i need to do.

**Camilo Terevinto** answered it good below.

Comment: im actually more suprised that it throws stack overflow instead of null arg since FormID is always null

Comment: The problem is that a new form is created before actually being added to the cache. So it ends up in and endless loop

Comment: OK? give a solution. Cache must hold single instance for each instance from Form that have unique FormID.  this mean each Form instance has instance inside a Cache with same FormID. so creating new instances from cloning the cache will be fast. thats what i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense:

```
if (!Cache.ContainsKey(FormID))
    Cache.Add(FormID, new Form());
```

You would always be checking/adding the default value of `FormId`. With that, you would ever only have a single key/value pair in that Dictionary, so using a Dictionary would be a waste.

You should use a factory method for this, and leave the default constructor alone:

```
private Form()
{
}

public static Form BuildForm(string formId)
{
    if (!Cache.ContainsKey(formId))
    {
        Cache.Add(formId, new Form());
    }

    return Cache[formId].DeepClone();  // using DeepCloner extension
}
```

Comment: @kokowawa Yes, assuming you correctly add them to the dictionary, it's not a waste. I said it is a waste if you only use a single `formId`

Comment: Why omitting default-constructor ! i love it why you kill my love ?

Comment: @kokowawa Because you need a constructor that does not interact with the cache and because you need the FormId to pass as the cache key

Comment: OK! you are chosen one !

Comment: OH, wait please what about DeepCloning the cache to new instances of Form that have same FormID ?  i mean should after `Cache.ContainsKey` in constructor inserting this line ? `this = Cache[FormID].DeepClone();`

Comment: @Camilio, i thing using static Form CreateNew() ? which will be good for cloning pattern ? not constructors thats will create new instance. as i meantioned not all new forms are instances ! some of them are cloned from cache !

Comment: it must be Deep Cloned because i nee two instance one for static. one for a normal instance. so it should return Cache[FormID].DeepClone() always. because if cache is already have form no problem. but it still need to Clone it always anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add `this` in the `Cache`:

```
public class Form
{
    internal static Dictionary<string, Form> Cache = new
        Dictionary<string, Form>();

    public string FormID { get; private set; }

    public Form(string formID)
    {
        this.FormID = formID;
        if (!Cache.ContainsKey(formID))
            Cache.Add(formID, this); // <--- this instead of new Form();
    }
}
```

`this` refers to the current `Form` instance that is been constructed.

Comment: I suggested this in a comment, the OP said they want a new instance, not `this`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I can't see the comment you refer to.

Comment: I deleted after the OP answered, but the OP deleted their comment as well, sorry for that

Comment: Yes, @Tgheodor this mean that the Cache[thisForm] will be targeted if static form changed. what i need is separate each instance of Form have only one static Form inside a Cache ! for re-using, cloning them for new instances which have same FormID ! that;s it

Comment: @kokowawa so you don't want to have two `Form` instances with the same `FormID`? Then you should not put this code in the constructor of the `Form`. You must have a static factory method that will create the requested form, or return an existing one from the `Cache`.

Comment: I mean, i have for example 100 forms. 10 of them is unique ( have same FormID ) and others is instantiated from this 10 forms ! but this 10 forms must be cached for re-cloning or instantiating them from cache to creating a new instances that have same FormID rather than creating new instance from scratch.  so a Cache contains only single FormID template. when i need create instance of Form that have a FormID in cache the instance is created by Deep Cloning the Cache static Form !! that's what i need. i also love default constructor why omitting it ?

Comment: I don't get it. If the 10 unique forms have the same FormID, then the other 90 non-unique forms have unique IDs? Do you mean something else?